# Question about RMAN-01009，RMAN-01007

Tags: oracle, rman

After i created the tablespace named "rman" and created the user named"rman" and accredited to the user.[image]

I connected to the recovery catalog database successfully.

But when i got into the next step.It mentioned ERROR.
[image]

Anyone could help me?
Thanks

Comment: The next step would be what? This is simply a syntax error in the command.

Comment: The next step is that i typed the command “rman target/catalog rman/rman@orcl”

Comment: @forest 251, you want to connect target database or else.

Comment: i want to connect target database and register

Comment: @forest251,Did you tried this '$ rman TARGET / CATALOG rman/rman@orcl;' may be there syntax error.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Is the command "catalog rman/rman”
 
“connect target;”

“rman>startup mount; ” equal to the command "$ rman TARGET / CATALOG rman/rman@orcl;"?

Comment: @forest 251,no.

Comment: @forest 251, It differ from your mode connection of RMAN like. some cases user want to "Connecting to the Target Database Without a Catalog from the RMAN Prompt " and some cases they want "Connecting to the Target Database and Recovery Catalog" . It depends on situation and environment. even i have sent the link you can go through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Connecting to the Target Database and Recovery Catalog**

The syntax will be below mention like that

```
rman TARGET / CATALOG rman/cat@catdb;
```

**where**

`rman` is Owner of the recovery catalog having RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER privilege.

`cat` is The password for user RMAN specified in the recovery catalog's orapwd file.

`catdb` is The net service name for the recovery catalog database.

for your further ref [Connecting to Databases with RMAN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96566/rcmcnctg.htm)